# How to use count() in condition

Tags: sql

Which GuestIDs have made more than 2 bookings?
I have query:

```
select guestid,count(BookingID)
from bookings
where 'count(bookingid)' < 2
group by guestid
```

it just shows all the count not the ones obove 2
plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 select guestId, count(bookingId) as booking_count
 from bookings
 group by guestId
 having count(bookingID) > 2
```

To apply conditions to aggregate values, you need to use the having clause. Also, you specified the comparison as "<" rather than ">". This could clearly cause confusion.

Comment: select guestId, count(bookingId) as booking_count
 from bookings
 group by guestid
 having count(bookingID) > 2

Comment: changed group by back to guestid and it worked 
thankyou for your help:)

Comment: glad you  found solution. Right - the gorup by has to be by guestId, not bookingId (how silly of me). I updated answer to reflect the change.